# SQL Server: Replace values in field via lookup other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently running into a challenge that probably has a easy solution, but somehow I am not able to come up with it.

I have Table A with two fields that are formatted as follows:

```
[ID]   [Codes]
 1      A;B
 2      D  
 3      A;C
```

And table B formatted as follows:

```
[ID]   [Codes]
 A     Apple
 B     Orange  
 C     Pear
 D     Strawberry
```

What I would like to do is a Lookup / Replace in order to generate the following output

```
a.[ID]   a.[Parsed_Codes]
  1     Apple;Orange
  2     Strawberry 
  3     Apple;Pear
```

In short I want to replace the codes in table A, with the values associated with those codes in table B.

Of course I could just write a long replace statement (in my case there are several 100 codes), but that seems like an extremely inefficient method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is by converting the **Table A** [Codes] `column data(csv) into separate rows.`
Then join with the **Table B** to get the respective codes. Finally `convert the rows to CSV` to get result. Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE #tablea
  ([ID]    INT,[Codes] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #tablea
VALUES      (1,'A;B'),(2,'D' ),(3,'A;C')

CREATE TABLE #tableB
  ([ID]    VARCHAR(100),[Codes] VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #tableb
VALUES      ('A','Apple'),( 'B','Orange' ),
            ('C','Pear'),('D','Strawberry')

SELECT a.id,
       a.Codes old_code,
       b.Codes Parsed_Codes
INTO   #final
FROM   #tableb b
       JOIN (SELECT id,
                    codes,
                    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') [new_Codes]
             FROM   (SELECT id,
                            [Codes],
                            Cast ('<M>' + Replace([Codes], ';', '</M><M>')
                                  + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
                     FROM   #tablea) AS A
                    CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) a
         ON a.new_Codes = b.id

SELECT t1.ID,
       old_code,
       Stuff((SELECT '; ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Parsed_Codes)
              FROM   #final b
              WHERE  b.ID = t1.ID
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM   #final t1
GROUP  BY t1.id,
          old_code
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID  old_code    Parsed_Codes
--  --------    ------------
1   A;B         Apple; Orange
2   D           Strawberry
3   A;C         Apple; Pear
```

(Note: temp table can be avoided to avoid code confusion i used temp table)

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. Work Like a Charm!

Answer (score 0):

First create this function.. It's used to split a delimited string, into a variable table. Then we would be able to use this function to determine the codes from the other table and return them as one string using the [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString]
   (
    @string NVarchar(MAX)
   ,@delimiter Char(1) = ','
   )
RETURNS @t TABLE (string NVarchar(MAX))
AS
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @pos Int
   DECLARE @piece Varchar(500)

   IF RIGHT(RTRIM(@string), 1) <> @delimiter
      SET @string = @string + @delimiter

   SET @pos = PATINDEX('%' + @delimiter + '%', @string)
   WHILE @pos <> 0
      BEGIN
         SET @piece = LEFT(@string, @pos - 1) 
         INSERT   @t
                  SELECT   @piece

         SET @string = STUFF(@string, 1, @pos, '')
         SET @pos = PATINDEX('%' + @delimiter + '%', @string)
      END 

   RETURN
END
```

Then run the following query...

```
DECLARE @result TABLE
   (
    [ID] Int
   ,[CommaDelimitedCodes] Varchar(500)
   )
DECLARE @codes TABLE
   (
    [ID] Varchar(500)
   ,[FullNames] Varchar(500)
   )
INSERT   INTO @result
         SELECT   1
                 ,'A;B'
INSERT   INTO @result
         SELECT   2
                 ,'D'
INSERT   INTO @result
         SELECT   3
                 ,'A;C'

INSERT   INTO @codes
         SELECT   'A'
                 ,'Apple'
INSERT   INTO @codes
         SELECT   'B'
                 ,'Orange'
INSERT   INTO @codes
         SELECT   'C'
                 ,'Pear'
INSERT   INTO @codes
         SELECT   'D'
                 ,'Strawberry'

SELECT   * 
        ,STUFF((
                SELECT  ', ' + [FullNames]
                FROM    @codes t
                WHERE   id IN (SELECT  *
                               FROM    dbo.fnSplitString(r.[CommaDelimitedCodes], ';'))
               FOR
                XML PATH('')
               ), 1, 2, '') AS taglist
FROM     @result AS r
```

I created two variable tables to test - but obviously in your case you'd need to replace those with actual field names in your tables.