# SQL Server: Replace values in field using lookup other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let's say I have below table script

```
DECLARE @result TABLE
   (
    [ID] Int
   ,[Data] Varchar(500)
   )
DECLARE @codes TABLE
   (
    [ID] Varchar(500)
   ,[FullNames] Varchar(500)
   )
INSERT   INTO @result
         SELECT   1
                 ,'[A]-[B]'
INSERT   INTO @result
         SELECT   2
                 ,'[D]-[A]'
INSERT   INTO @result
         SELECT   3
                 ,'[A]+[C]'

INSERT   INTO @codes
         SELECT   'A'
                 ,'10'
INSERT   INTO @codes
         SELECT   'B'
                 ,'20'
INSERT   INTO @codes
         SELECT   'C'
                 ,'30'
INSERT   INTO @codes
         SELECT   'D'
                 ,'40'

SELECT * FROM @result
SELECT * FROM @codes
```

Output of those are as below:
@result

```
ID  Data
--  -------
1   [A]-[B]
2   [D]-[A]
3   [A]+[C]
```

@codes

```
ID  FullNames
--  -------
A   10
B   20
C   30
D   40
```

Now I want output as below also:

```
ID  Data
--  -----
1   10-20
2   40-10
3   10+30
```

Please help me.
Please note: Data columns also contains ([A]-[B]+[D])*[C]

I found similar solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/26650255/8454103 which is for your reference.

Comment: This is going to be incredibly inefficient and cumbersome to do with SQL.  The language isn't meant to do this sort of operation in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
select Output from (
select Data, c1.FullNames as LeftSideName, c2.FullNames as RightSideName, LeftSide, RightSide, REPLACE(REPLACE(Data,'[' + LeftSide + ']',c1.FullNames),'[' + RightSide + ']',c2.FullNames) as Output from (
select r.ID, Data,SUBSTRING(Data, 2, 1) LeftSide ,SUBSTRING(Data, 6, 1) RightSide from @result r ) Result
inner join @codes c1 ON Result.LeftSide = c1.ID
inner join @codes c2 ON Result.RightSide = c2.ID)
Records

Output:
10-20
10+30
40-10
```

The query can perform replacing dynamically *A,B,C,D,E* according to `@codes` table etc.

Comment: Could you please check your query with Data columns also contains ([A]-[B]+[D])*[C]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ID, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Data,
            '[A]', (select FullNames from @codes where ID = 'A')),
            '[B]', (select FullNames from @codes where ID = 'B')),
            '[C]', (select FullNames from @codes where ID = 'C')),
            '[D]', (select FullNames from @codes where ID = 'D'))
from @result
```